# Website code works fine on Chrome and Firefox, desktop or mobile, but does not work on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, frontend, mobile-safari, velo

A certain piece of my website works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but does not seem to work on Safari. I checked and all the people trying the website on iPhones had Javascript enabled. Is there something about my code that cannot be read by Safari? Are there any tools out there to test how code would be perceived on Safari that I can use with a windows computer?

Below is the code to the piece of my website. I had to replace all images and text with different content because I am forbidden to share the actual content. Essentially, this piece of the website would allow someone to input a certain metric in, via a slider bar, and see what something would look like with said metric. The slider bar seems to be movable, but images are not appearing, nor are they moving when viewing through Safari. As an additional note, I converted this code to https (what Wix refers to as all in one text block) and inserted it into my Wix website as an html element.

I realize that my JavaScript has quite a few redundancies, such as defining the same variable locally twice instead of defining it globally once. I'm looking to fix those later and get this working first (although this could be why it doesn't work on Safari?). I've never developed anything before, so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Update: I had a few people send me screenshots and the slider bar AND javascript are working, the images are just not showing up on Safari.

HTML

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Box-->
    <div class="wholething">
      <div class="box">
        <!-- Dude -->
        <img class="img-square img-dude" src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/ff/5a/74/ff5a741afd59d527f4492c593b329106--free-clipart-downloads-free-clipart-images.jpg" id="dude" </img>

        <!-- Banana-->
        <img class="img-square img-bn" src=" https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Candy-clipart.svg" id="flag">
        </img>

        <div class="whitebox" id="whiteboxID">
        </div>

        <img class="gorilla" src="https://openclipart.org/download/249534/1464300474.svg" id="gorillaID" </img>

      </div>

      <h1 class="sliderlabel" id="sliderlabelID">Hunger level</h1>
      <h1 class="sliderlabelinfo" id="sliderlabelinfoID">(drag to select)</h1>

      <!-- Slider -->
      <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="3" max="10" value="5" step="0.1" class="slider" id="inchslider">
        <output name="rangeVal" id="value"></output>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wholething {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  background-color: #F5F4EF;
  height: 60%;
  width: 81.25%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.img-dude {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 90%;
}

.img-bn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 10.125%;
}

.whitebox {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F5F4EF;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: calc(15% + 15px);
  width: calc(15% + 20px);
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gorilla {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 90%;
  display: none;
}

.sliderlabel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12.5%;
  top: 61%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.sliderlabelinfo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12.5%;
  top: 66.5%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.slidervalue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 28.5%;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-apperance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.15, #4BD1A0), color-stop(0.15, #F5F4EF));
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #4BD1A0;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover+output {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #4BD1A0;
}

.slider:active {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #4BD1A0;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #4BD1A0;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #F5F4EF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

output {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(28.57% + 3.25px);
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #4BD1A0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

input[type=range]:hover+output {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

input[type=range]:active+output {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

input[type=range] {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.2857, #4BD1A0), color-stop(0.2857, #F5F4EF))
}

output:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid #4BD1A0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 40%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('dude'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    width = style.getPropertyValue('width'),
    height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
  var slicedwidth = width.slice(0, -2);
  var slicedheight = height.slice(0, -2);
  var widthmargarin = ((Number(slicedwidth) * 0.55) + 20).toString() + "px";
  var heightmargarin = (Number(slicedheight) * 0.488).toString() + "px";
  var whiteboxwidthmargarin = ((Number(slicedwidth) * 0.55) + 25).toString() + "px";
  document.getElementById("flag").style.marginLeft = widthmargarin;
  document.getElementById("flag").style.marginBottom = heightmargarin;
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "5 points";
  document.getElementById("whiteboxID").style.marginLeft = whiteboxwidthmargarin;
});

function setIcon(x, y) {
  var element = document.getElementById('dude'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    width = style.getPropertyValue('width'),
    left = style.getPropertyValue('left'),
    height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
  var slicedwidth = width.slice(0, -2);
  var slicedheight = height.slice(0, -2);
  var widthmargarin = ((Number(slicedwidth) * 0.55) + (((x - 5) / 100 * 4.6) * Number(slicedwidth)) + 20).toString() + "px";
  var heightmargarin = ((Number(slicedheight) * 0.485) + (((y - 5) / 100 * 0.5) * Number(slicedheight))).toString() + "px";
  document.getElementById("flag").style.marginLeft = widthmargarin;
  document.getElementById("flag").style.marginBottom = heightmargarin;
  document.getElementById("flag").style.transform = "rotate(" + (7 - (x * 1.3)) + "deg)";
  document.getElementById("whiteboxID").style.marginLeft = (Number(widthmargarin.slice(0, -2)) + 5).toString() + "px";
  document.getElementById("whiteboxID").style.transform = "rotate(" + (7 - (x * 1.5)) + "deg)";
}

var slider = document.getElementById("inchslider");
var output = document.getElementById("value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  var positionXslider = 0;
  var positionYslider = 0;
  if (this.value >= 5) {
    positionXslider = output.innerHTML;
    positionYslider = output.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("flag").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Candy-clipart.svg";
  } else if (this.value >= 4 && this.value < 5) {
    positionXslider = 5;
    positionYslider = 5;
    document.getElementById("flag").src = "https://openclipart.org/download/284444/1502025489.svg";
  } else if (this.value < 4) {
    positionXslider = 5;
    positionYslider = 5;
    document.getElementById("flag").src = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/slice-pizza-on-white-background-260nw-597727904.jpg";
  } else {
    positionXslider = output.innerHTML;
    positionYslider = output.innerHTML;
  }
  setIcon(positionXslider, positionYslider);

};

$('input[type="range"]').on('input', function() {
  var val = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min')) / ($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));

  $(this).css('background-image',
    '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, ' +
    'color-stop(' + val + ', #4BD1A0), ' +
    'color-stop(' + val + ', #F5F4EF)' +
    ')'
  );
});

$('input[type="range"]').on('input', function() {

  var control = $(this),
    controlMin = control.attr('min'),
    controlMax = control.attr('max'),
    controlVal = control.val(),
    controlThumbWidth = 25;

  var range = controlMax - controlMin;

  var position = ((controlVal - controlMin) / range) * 100;
  var positionOffset = Math.round(controlThumbWidth * position / 100) - (controlThumbWidth / 2) + 2.25;
  var output = control.next('output');
  var controlValNumber = Number(controlVal)
  var controlValLabel = 0;

  if (controlValNumber >= 5) {
    controlValLabel = controlVal.slice(0, 3);
  } else if (controlValNumber >= 4 && controlValNumber < 5) {
    controlValLabel = 4;
  } else if (controlValNumber < 4) {
    controlValLabel = 3;
  }

  if (controlValNumber >= 10) {
    document.getElementById("gorillaID").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("gorillaID").style.display = "none";
  }

  output
    .css('left', 'calc(' + position + '% - ' + positionOffset + 'px)')
    .text(controlValLabel + " points")
});
```

Comment: perhaps safari is especially sensitive to rubbish HTML -  1 - images do NOT have a  closing tag, and 2 - you have basically `<img attributes </img>` instead of `<img attributes />` can you see how far from correct your code is? As for anything else .. that's what browsers have a **developer** console for - for *developers* to see what they've done wrong

Comment: Thanks for the help on the img tags, didn't know that. How can I access the developer console for Safari if I can't download it? I can't find Safari for Windows and am searching for ways to debug this in Safari.

Comment: well, that's an issue every developer faces